# Bootstrap 4 custom radio form labels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, radio-button, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've got a problem with my Bootstrap 4.0 (Stable) form.
I want to add a label to my radio buttons but its not formatting prob.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">Test</label>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="ja" id="handicapped-ja" name="handicapped">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="handicapped">Ja</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="nein" id="handicapped-nein" name="handicapped">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="handicapped">Nein</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 you could do that with `span` and custom-controls. In 4.0 Stable its not working anymore. Is there a new way i cant find in the doku to do that?

BSP:

```
<label class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input id="mixed0" name="cat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">No</span>
</label>
```

Comment: What does not formatting properly mean? What do you expect?

Comment: I want to have a Description for the radio buttons. As you see the possibilies are only yes/no and i need two of them its hard for the customers to see what they are picking with these buttons ;) And it needs to be inline